# Query problem with multiple relation's column as condition

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

I have a table "books":

| book_id (PK) | date_added | date_updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2022-07-30 | 2022-07-31 |
| 101 | 2022-07-28 |  |
| 102 | 2022-07-27 |  |
| 103 | 2022-07-27 |  |

and another one "book_details":

| attribute_id (PK) | book_id (FK) | param_1 | param_2 | param_3 | param_4 | param_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | A | A | B | C | Corporate and municipal securities |
| 2 | 100 | A | B | B | A | Marva J. Dawn |
| 3 | 101 | A | A | B | C | Lucky |
| 4 | 101 | A | B | B | A | Ruth Haley Barton |
| 5 | 101 | A | C | A | A | 9786029254464 |
| 6 | 102 | A | A | B | C | Truly the community |
| 7 | 103 | A | A | B | C | Index to the library of investment banking |
| 8 | 103 | A | B | B | A | Marva J. Dawn |

In the second table, param_1-4 are required parameters which define the attribute of the book. For example:

param_1: **A**; param_2: **A**; param_3: **B**; param_4: **C** means "Book's title", and

param_1: **A**; param_2: **B**; param_3: **B**; param_4: **A** means "Book's author", it means book with ID: 100 has a title of "Corporate and municipal securities" and written by "Marva J. Dawn".

If I search for books with title that contained word: "muni", it will return two book_id: 100 and 102, and if I search for the author "dawn", it will return book_id: 100 and 103. How should I work the query so that when I search for title: "muni" and author: "dawn", it will only return one book_id: **100**

So far I tried using this:

```
SELECT book_id FROM books AS b, book_details AS bd WHERE b.book_id = bd.book_id AND ((param_1 = 'A' AND param_2 = 'A' AND param_3 = 'B' AND param_4 = 'C' AND param_value ILIKE '%muni%') AND (param_1 = 'A' AND param_2 = 'B' AND param_3 = 'B' AND param_4 = 'C' AND param_value ILIKE '%dawn%'))
```

but resulted with empty row. If I used 'OR' to combine the two conditions:

```
SELECT book_id FROM books AS b, book_details AS bd WHERE b.book_id = bd.book_id AND ((param_1 = 'A' AND param_2 = 'A' AND param_3 = 'B' AND param_4 = 'C' AND param_value ILIKE '%muni%') OR (param_1 = 'A' AND param_2 = 'B' AND param_3 = 'B' AND param_4 = 'C' AND param_value ILIKE '%dawn%')) GROUP BY book_id
```

it will return two result, book_id: 100 and 103.

For additional info, I'm using PostgreSQL and currently developing search function for a website with Laravel framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is with a self join, like this:

```
SELECT bd1.book_id 
FROM book_details bd1
JOIN book_details bd2 on bd1.book_id = bd2.book_id 
WHERE bd1.param_1 = 'A' 
AND bd1.param_2 = 'A' 
AND bd1.param_3 = 'B' 
AND bd1.param_4 = 'C' 
AND bd1.param_value ILIKE '%muni%' 
AND bd2.param_1 = 'A' 
AND bd2.param_2 = 'B' 
AND bd2.param_3 = 'B' 
AND bd2.param_4 = 'A' 
AND bd2.param_value ILIKE '%dawn%';
```

Note a couple of things.  I have left out the books table.  If you only want the id, then this exists in the book_details table, so there is no need of a join to books.  Secondly, the requirement for some sort of join, is due to the fact that the title and author are in different rows of the table.

An alternative approach would be to use a where exists like this:

```
SELECT bd.book_id 
FROM book_details bd
WHERE bd.param_1 = 'A' 
AND bd.param_2 = 'A' 
AND bd.param_3 = 'B' 
AND bd.param_4 = 'C' 
AND bd.param_value ILIKE '%muni%' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM book_details 
            WHERE param_1 = 'A' 
            AND param_2 = 'B' 
            AND param_3 = 'B' 
            AND param_4 = 'A' 
            AND param_value ILIKE '%dawn%'
            AND book_id = bd.book_id);
```

This is simply saying give me the book_id where the title is the desired one, and where there is also an author for the same book_id whose name is the desired one.

One advantage of the first alternative is that it allows you to get more data easily.  For example you could expand the `select` to:

```
SELECT bd1.book_id, bd1.param_value as title, bd2.param_value as author
```

Comment: Sorry I scrolled past your answer without realizing it, since it's already 1 past midnight :) since your answer solved my problem, I mark yours as the solution, since @Eric's solution still require some edits. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think this query will help you.
If it won't work, let me know again.

```
SELECT
    book_title.book_id,
    book_title.param_value,
    book_author.param_value,
    books.date_added
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            book_details
        WHERE
            param_1 = 'A'
            AND param_2 = 'A'
            AND param_3 = 'B'
            AND param_4 = 'C'
            AND param_value LIKE '%muni%'
    ) book_title
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            book_details
        WHERE
            param_1 = 'A'
            AND param_2 = 'B'
            AND param_3 = 'B'
            AND param_4 = 'A'
            AND param_value LIKE '%dawn%'
    ) book_author ON book_title.book_id = book_author.book_id
    LEFT JOIN books ON book_title.book_id = books.book_id
```

Comment: A left join is going to return 2 records in this case, and  the OP specifically asked for one record.

Comment: As @JonathanWillcock said, it returned two record

Comment: Instead of LEFT JOIN, I tried to change the first LEFT JOIN with book_author to INNER JOIN and it solved my problem. If you could, please kindly edit your answer, so that I can mark it as the solution